# Separate 1000 in ActiveX textbox

Tags: excel

I am wondering how it is possible to separate 1000 in ActiveX textbox. I have searched in Properties for some kind of Format field but can't figure out how this can be achieved?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a change event to the TextBox with your format

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Format(Me.TextBox1.Text, "#" & Application.ThousandsSeparator & "###")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

So right click on ActiveX textbox -> View code.

```
Private Sub TextBox12_Change()
    TextBox12.Value = Format(TextBox12.Value, "###,##")
End Sub
```